# Procedure for GoDaddy and AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, godaddy, amazon-route53, domain-transferring

My boss host a domain e.g. `example.com` in GoDaddy. (I do not have access to GoDaddy this case)

In AWS, I want to setup a load-balancer (ELB) and point to 2 EC2 servers.

Unfortunately, I can't setup "@" A record to ELB due to DNS features.

I want to utilize Route53 to do it but my boss don't want to transfer the domain to Amazon. Is it possible?

My question is, whether I need to transfer `example.com` from GoDaddy to Amazon. (Of course, if I need to make some changes in GoDaddy side, it make sense to my boss). Is it ok? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to transfer the domain, you just need to point the nameservers at Route53. The domain can stay at GoDaddy for the registrar.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy can still be a domain registrar while you'll have to update it with 4 name servers assigned to your Route 53 Hosted Zone (visible as NS record in a Hosted Zone): https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us-12317. In Route 53 Hosted Zone you can create an alias record to an ELB instance.